# onEdit detect the change of cell background colour, then write the value to Sheet1

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Automate, Whenever I fill any cell of Column B of any Sheet with red colour. It should automatically pastes the cell in column A of sheet specific sheet.

I used this code :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var color = range.getBackground();
  var destinationSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');

  if (color == "#ff0000" && range.getColumn() == 2) {
    var data = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1).getValue();
    var lastRow = destinationSheet.getLastRow();
    destinationSheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue(data);
  }
}
```

But everytime it give error of cannot read properties of undefined reading 'range'.

Comment: 1. onEdit does not specifically detect changes in background colour. 2. onEdit works automatically when you edit a cell. When you run the script from the script editor then no event occurred, so no event is captured, and so the event is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `onEdit` simple trigger cannot detect background colour changes, you would need to use an `On change` installable trigger instead.

To detect the background colour change requires to detect that the `changeType` is `'FORMAT'`.

Based on your example script, here is a modified script that observes the same conditions:

```
function detectBackgroundColourChange(e) {
  if (e.changeType != 'FORMAT') {
    return;
  }
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  const colour = range.getBackground();
  const cellColour = "#ff0000"; // Change this to the desired background colour in hex
  if (colour === cellColour && range.getColumn() === 2) {
    const data = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1).getValue();
    const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    const lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
    targetSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(data);
  }
}
```

Screengrab showing the script working as requested:

[image: screengrab showing the script working]

Sample file for you to make a copy of, and setup your own trigger:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aNOIdtYXeQa_NmJ5r1Dn_YCli-cFf98cGCNK0HKAfr0/copy

Documentation:
[Simple Triggers  |  Apps Script  |  Google for Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: When I use this code, I get error = TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'changeType'). Can you suggest me solution?

Comment: After running the script in the editor (which will of course fail), did you then create the installable trigger, or not?

Comment: @HriteshKumar was your problem solved or not?

Comment: I used OnChange trigger. But it gets error rate: 100% . The error I get now is TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBackground') . I have changed the code a little bit and it still doesn't work.

Comment: detectBackgroundColourChange(e) {
  if (e && e.changeType === 'FORMAT') {
    const ss = e.source;
    const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    const range = e.range;
    const colour = range.getBackground();
    const cellColour = "#ff0000";
    if (colour === cellColour && range.getColumn() === 2) {
      const data = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1).getValue();
      const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      const lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
      targetSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(data);
    }
  }
}

Comment: @HriteshKumar. do NOT make any changes to the script. You asked for help because your script was not working. So modifying a script that has been tested as working is NOT going to solve your problem. I have added screenshot to my answer showing the script is working once the On change trigger was installed. You can make a copy of the file, then follow the instructions exactly as given.

Comment: @HriteshKumar, you did not change it  "a little bit" .. you completely changed it and the changes you made will NOT work. When someone gives a script you should test it exactly as given and not change it then say it is not working when the fact is that it is YOUR script (not the given script) that is not working.

Comment: Chill mate, modifying a script is a good thing. Btw, Thanks your script worked. I have adjusted it so that it gets the data of the red coloured cell and paste it into the available row of column A:A and not the last row.

Comment: Hey mate, I was wondering if we can get number of followers an Instagram account has, using link which is already in Column B. Is it possible?

Comment: @HriteshKumar if the script worked, then the standard thing to do is mark the answer as "Accepted". For your new question, make a new enquiry.

Comment: Already Did ; )

Answer (score 0):

You could have written like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  var color = e.range.getBackground();
  var dsh = e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  if (sh.getName() == "Your sheet name" && color == "#ff0000" && e.range.columnStart == 2) {
    var data = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).getValue();
    dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(data);
  }
}
```

But of course the big problem for you is that onEdit() does not trigger on background changes

Your could possible add a column of check boxes and do it this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  var dsh = e.source.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  if (e.value = "TRUE" && e.range.columnStart == "checkbox column number") {
    dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1).setValue(sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1).getValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: still getting: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')

Comment: You cannot run this function without supplying the event object.  It is intended to be executed by an onEdit trigger which occurs when you edit a cell in a spreadsheet.

Comment: I used OnChange trigger because of the function detectbackgroundchange

Comment: Still It doesn't work

Comment: function detectBackgroundColourChange(e) {
  if (e && e.changeType === 'FORMAT') {
    const ss = e.source;
    const sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    const range = e.range;
    const colour = range.getBackground();
    const cellColour = "#ff0000";
    if (colour === cellColour && range.getColumn() === 2) {
      const data = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 1).getValue();
      const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1'); 
      const lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1;
      targetSheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(data);
    }
  }
}

Comment: I get this error= [TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getBackground')] Even after supplying the event object.

Comment: Where does this error occur? What line?

Comment: Did you supply your own event object and the called the onEdit function with an intermediate function?  If so please post a copy of that intermediate function in your question.  It sounds like your supply range may not be correct.

Comment: Thanks for being cooperative and understanding. My issue is solved now mate.

Comment: Hey mate, I was wondering if we can get number of followers an Instagram account has, using link which is already in Column B. Is it possible?